# flattening a list of contracts based on priority

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, loops, flatten

I have a list of contracts that has a timespan to be finished in. Some contracts are more important than others. If there is an overlap between two contracts we cut down the less important one in a way that will either cut in two, cut it from the start or the end or fully remove it.

My problem is: I've implemented the algorithm but I still have some minor errors which cause a false output.
e.g.

```
Input:
Start     Ende        Preis  Priorität
1.1.2020  1.3.2020    20,40  1
1.2.2020  31.12.2020  18,00  2
1.6.2020  1.9.2020    16,90  3

Output should be:
Start     Ende        Preis
1.1.2020  31.1.2020   20,40
1.2.2020  31.5.2020   18,00
1.6.2020  1.9.2020    16,90
2.9.2020  31.12.2020  18,00
```

My Code:

```
List<Contract> contractList = //get value based on a file and get sorted based on the priority;
List<Contract> resultContracts = new List<Contract>()
{
    contractList[0]
};
int n = contractList.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < contractList.Count; i++)
{

    var lastProcessedContract = contractList[i]; // high priority
    var contractsToRemove = new List<Contract>();
    var contractsToAdd = new List<Contract>();
    for (var j = i + 1;  j < contractList.Count; j++){

        var lessPriorityContract = contractList[j];
        if (contractList[j].priority == contractList[i].priority)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (lessPriorityContract.start >= lastProcessedContract.start && lessPriorityContract.end <= lastProcessedContract.end)
        /*
         *  ------------------------>
         *           ------>
         * oder
         *  ------------------------>
         *  -------->
         * oder
         *  ------------------------->
         *                    ------->
         * oder
         * --------------------------->
         * --------------------------->
         */
        {
            contractsToRemove.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
        else if ((lessPriorityContract.start < lastProcessedContract.start 
                 && (lessPriorityContract.end > lastProcessedContract.start && lessPriorityContract.end <= lastProcessedContract.end)) || 
                 ((lastProcessedContract.start < lessPriorityContract.end && lastProcessedContract.start > lessPriorityContract.start)
                     && lastProcessedContract.end > lessPriorityContract.end))
       /* 
          *     ------------------------>
          *  ------>
          * oder
          *     ------------------------------->
          * ----------------------------------->

        // oder

          *                   -------------->
          *  ------------------------>
        */

        {
            lessPriorityContract.end = lastProcessedContract.start.AddDays(-1);
            resultContracts.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
        else if (((lessPriorityContract.start < lastProcessedContract.end && lessPriorityContract.start >= lastProcessedContract.start)
                 && lessPriorityContract.end > lastProcessedContract.end) || (lastProcessedContract.start < lessPriorityContract.start &&
                                                                              (lastProcessedContract.end > lessPriorityContract.start && lastProcessedContract.end < lessPriorityContract.end)))
        /*
         * -------------------->
         *            ------------------------->
         * oder
         * -------------------->
         * ---------------------------------->
         *

        //oder

          *  ------------>
          *       ------------------->
          * 
         */ 
        {
            lessPriorityContract.start = lastProcessedContract.end.AddDays(1);
            resultContracts.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
        else if(lessPriorityContract.start < lastProcessedContract.start
                && lessPriorityContract.end > lastProcessedContract.end)
            /*
             *       ------------>
             * --------------------------->
             * oder
             * --------------------------->
             * --------------------------->
             * 
             */
        {
            contractsToRemove.Add(lessPriorityContract);
            var contract = new Contract
            {
                start = lessPriorityContract.start,
                end = lastProcessedContract.start.AddDays(-1),
                priority = lessPriorityContract.priority,
                price = lessPriorityContract.price
            };
            contractsToAdd.Add(contract);

            //contractList.Remove(contractList[i]);
            //contractList.Add(contract);
            resultContracts.Add(contract);
            contract = new Contract
            {
                start = lastProcessedContract.end.AddDays(1),
                end = lessPriorityContract.end,
                priority = lessPriorityContract.priority,
                price = lessPriorityContract.price
            };
            resultContracts.Add(contract);
            contractsToAdd.Add(contract);

            //contractList.Add(contract);
        }
        else
        {
            resultContracts.Add(lessPriorityContract);
        }
    }
    foreach (var contractToRemove in contractsToRemove)
    {
        contractList.Remove(contractToRemove);
        resultContracts.Remove(contractToRemove);
    }

    foreach (var contractToAdd in contractsToAdd)
    {
        contractList.Add(contractToAdd);
    }
    contractList.Sort();
}

resultContracts.Sort(new ContractComparer()); // Sorting based on start time of the contract
resultContracts = resultContracts.Distinct().ToList();
foreach (var flatElement in resultContracts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flatElement.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}

resultContracts.Sort();
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
foreach (var flatElement in resultContracts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flatElement.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The Class Contract has attributes(start, end, price, priority) and an overridden Method from `Icomparable` to help sort based on priority.

I am open to get new efficient and faster algorithms too, otherwise repairing this would be also helpful.

edit: small notice is I am not concerned right now on how many attributes I am outputting as long as I solve the algorithm I can take care of that :)

Comment: What should happen when two contracts have the same priority?

Comment: that could not be the case because the exercise assumes that the csv does not have such data where two contracts have the same priority and time. but if you mean if the one contracts will be split in two so we have two contracts with the same priority that should be fine because they will never overlap on each because they were once in the same timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend taking a step back and generalizing first. At the core your problem is about "cutting" a date range based on another date range. So let's solve that first:

```
public record DateRange(DateTime From, DateTime To) {
    public bool Overlaps(DateRange other) => From <= other.To && other.From <= To;

    public IEnumerable<DateRange> Cut(DateRange other) {
        if (!Overlaps(other)) {
            yield return this;
        } else if (From >= other.From && To > other.To) {
            yield return this with { From = other.To.AddDays(1) };
        } else if (From < other.From && To <= other.To) {
            yield return this with { To = other.From.AddDays(-1) };
        } else if (From < other.From && To > other.To) {
            yield return this with { To = other.From.AddDays(-1) };
            yield return this with { From = other.To.AddDays(1) };
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a type for date ranges and an operation on them called "cut" which can shorten, split, or completely "remove" a date range based on its overlap with another date range. Or it will leave the date range as is when there is no overlap. I'll add the test class to the end of this answer as a proof of work.

Because we're working with not only two, but possibly many more date ranges from contracts, we can add another method to `DateRange` in order to help us:

```cs
public IEnumerable<DateRange> CutAll(IEnumerable<DateRange> others) => others
    .Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Repeat(this, 1),
        (cuts, other) => cuts.SelectMany(s => s.Cut(other)));
```

This will split a date range into lots of "sub date ranges" if it overlaps with multiple others.

**Your business code now boils down to:**

- Sort contracts by priority (ascending).
- Iterate over contracts:

  - Cut the current contract's date range with all the date ranges of its successors in the list.
  - Use the date range cut results to create "sub contracts" from the current contract.

Here's an example how this might look like in (untested) code:

```cs
var contracts = new List<Contract> {
    new(Period: new(From: new(2020, 01, 01), To: new(2020, 03, 01)), Price: 20.40m, Priority: 1),
    new(Period: new(From: new(2020, 02, 01), To: new(2020, 12, 31)), Price: 18.00m, Priority: 2),
    new(Period: new(From: new(2020, 06, 01), To: new(2020, 09, 01)), Price: 16.90m, Priority: 3)
};

for (var i = 0; i < contracts.Count; i++) {
    var current = contracts[i];
    var successors = contracts[(i + 1)..];
    var subDateRanges = current.Period.CutAll(successors.Select(c => c.Period));

    foreach (var dr in subDateRanges) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{dr.From} {dr.To} {current.Price} {current.Priority}");
    }
}

public record Contract(DateRange Period, decimal Price, int Priority);
```

---

```cs
namespace Tests;

using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

public static class DateRangeTests {
    public class Overlaps {
        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsFalseWhenRangesDontOverlap1() =>
            Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-15")
            .Overlaps(Range("2019-01-20", "2019-01-31"))
            .Should().BeFalse();

        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsFalseWhenRangesDontOverlap2() =>
            Range("2019-01-20", "2019-01-31")
            .Overlaps(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-15"))
            .Should().BeFalse();

        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsTrueWhenRangesOverlap1() =>
            Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-20")
            .Overlaps(Range("2019-01-15", "2019-01-31"))
            .Should().BeTrue();

        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsTrueWhenRangesOverlap2() =>
            Range("2019-01-15", "2019-01-31")
            .Overlaps(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-20"))
            .Should().BeTrue();

        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsTrueWhenRangesOverlap3() =>
            Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-31")
            .Overlaps(Range("2019-01-10", "2019-01-20"))
            .Should().BeTrue();

        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsTrueWhenRangesOverlap4() =>
            Range("2019-01-10", "2019-01-20")
            .Overlaps(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-31"))
            .Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public class Cut {
        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsLeftSideWhenRightSideDoesNotOverlap() =>
            Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-10")
            .Cut(Range("2019-01-20", "2019-01-31"))
            .Should().ContainSingle().Which.Should().Be(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-10"));

        [Fact]
        public void AbsorbsLeftSideWhenRightSideOverlapsCompletely() =>
            Range("2019-01-10", "2019-01-20")
            .Cut(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-31"))
            .Should().BeEmpty();

        [Fact]
        public void MovesStartOfLeftSideWhenRightSideOverlapsBeginning() =>
            Range("2019-01-10", "2019-01-20")
            .Cut(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-15"))
            .Should().ContainSingle().Which.Should().Be(Range("2019-01-16", "2019-01-20"));

        [Fact]
        public void MovesEndOfLeftSideWhenRightSideOverlapsEnd() =>
            Range("2019-01-10", "2019-01-20")
            .Cut(Range("2019-01-15", "2019-01-25"))
            .Should().ContainSingle().Which.Should().Be(Range("2019-01-10", "2019-01-14"));

        [Fact]
        public void SplitsLeftSideWhenRightSideIsInside() =>
            Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-31")
            .Cut(Range("2019-01-15", "2019-01-25"))
            .Should().SatisfyRespectively(
                dr1 => dr1.Should().Be(Range("2019-01-01", "2019-01-14")),
                dr2 => dr2.Should().Be(Range("2019-01-26", "2019-01-31")));
    }

    public class CutAll {
        [Fact]
        public void CutsLeftSideByAllFromRightSide() =>
            Range("2019-02-01", "2019-02-28")
            .CutAll([Range("2019-01-01", "2019-02-03"), Range("2019-02-10", "2019-02-15"), Range("2019-02-25", "2019-03-31")])
            .Should().SatisfyRespectively(
                dr1 => dr1.Should().Be(Range("2019-02-04", "2019-02-09")),
                dr2 => dr2.Should().Be(Range("2019-02-16", "2019-02-24")));

        [Fact]
        public void ReturnsLeftSideWhenRightSideIsEmpty() =>
            Range("2019-02-01", "2019-02-28")
            .CutAll([])
            .Should().ContainSingle().Which.Should().Be(Range("2019-02-01", "2019-02-28"));
    }

    private static DateRange Range(string from, string to) => new(DateTime.Parse(from), DateTime.Parse(to));
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. but I can't seem to make a difference between these two conditions:
From < other.From && To > other.To
and
From <= other.To && other.From <= To

I tried to visualize it by putting two arrow on a time line but I seem to get the same condition which is "other" is overlapping on the current

Comment: @MouadMeziani The 1st condition checks if `this` completely contains `other`. The 2nd condition is a ([kinda unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/1025555)) shortcut for checking if two ranges overlap in any way. I don't think it would be hard to derive it yourself with boolean algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Declarations for a timeline algorithm (using C# 12):

```cs
using System.Globalization;
// Tuple used in the timeline
using Event = (System.DateOnly Date, bool IsStart, ContractPriorities.Contract Contract);

namespace ContractPriorities;

public record Contract(DateOnly Start, DateOnly End, decimal Price, int Priority)
{
    public Contract(string Start, string End, decimal Price, int Priority)
        : this(DateOnly.Parse(Start, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
              DateOnly.Parse(End, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
              Price, Priority)
    {
    }
}
```

Test setup:

```cs
List<Contract> contractList = [
    new("2020-01-01", "2020-03-01", 20.40m, 1),
    new("2020-02-01", "2020-12-31", 18.00m, 2),
    new("2020-06-01", "2020-09-01", 16.90m, 3),
];
```

The idea is to create a timeline where all the events (start or end of a contract) are listed.

```cs
var timeLine = contractList
    .Select(c => new Event(c.Start, true, c))
    .Concat(
        contractList
        .Select(c => new Event(c.End, false, c))
    )
    .OrderBy(t => t.Date)
    .ThenBy(t => t.IsStart ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.Contract.Priority);
```

- We assume that contracts with same priority do not overlap in time (according to your comment).
- We assume that a higher priority number represents a higher priority.

We create an array where we store the currently running contracts by priority where the array index is the priority number. Since these numbers start at 1 and the arrays are 0-based, we ignore array element 0 and make the array on element larger than the number of priorities.

```cs
const int NumerOfPriorities = 3;
var currentContracts = new Contract?[NumerOfPriorities + 1]; // We ignore item[0].
List<Contract> result = [];
Contract? activeContract = null;
```

Then we can loop through the timeline and take the appropriate actions.

```cs
foreach (var (date, isStart, contract) in timeLine) {
    if (isStart) {
        currentContracts[contract.Priority] = contract;
        if (activeContract is null) {
            activeContract = contract;
        } else if (activeContract.Priority < contract.Priority) {
            if (activeContract.Start < date) {
                result.Add(activeContract with { End = date.AddDays(-1) });
            }
            activeContract = contract;
        }
    } else {
        if (activeContract?.End == contract.End &&
            activeContract?.Priority == contract.Priority &&
            activeContract.Start <= activeContract.End) {
            // The active contract is the one how ends.
            result.Add(activeContract);
        }
        currentContracts[contract.Priority] = null;
        Contract? highPrioContract = currentContracts.LastOrDefault(c => c != null);
        DateOnly? lastEnd = result.Count == 0 ? null : result[^1].End;
        if (lastEnd.HasValue && highPrioContract?.Start <= lastEnd) {
            highPrioContract = highPrioContract with { Start = lastEnd.Value.AddDays(1) };
        }
        activeContract = highPrioContract;
    }
}
```

This test

```cs
foreach (var contract in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(contract);
}
```

produces this result:

```
Contract { Start = 01.01.2020, End = 31.01.2020, Price = 20.40, Priority = 1 }
Contract { Start = 01.02.2020, End = 31.05.2020, Price = 18.00, Priority = 2 }
Contract { Start = 01.06.2020, End = 01.09.2020, Price = 16.90, Priority = 3 }
Contract { Start = 02.09.2020, End = 31.12.2020, Price = 18.00, Priority = 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

My [first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77548262/880990) based on the events timeline involves complex logic to check for overlaps and edge cases.

Here is another straightforward solution based on day buckets. The basic idea is to create an array containing a bucket for each day in the period under consideration.

- First, we fill the buckets with every day of each contract. The logic is very straight forward: If a bucket is empty or contains a contract with a lower priority, we replace it with the current contract, otherwise we leave the bucket as is.
- Then we loop through all the buckets and regroup equal adjacent contracts to form the results. The start and end indexes of a contract in the array correspond to the start and end dates of a contract period.

The algorithm is quite simple and robust.

```cs
public List<Contract> FlattenContracts(List<Contract> contractList)
{
    List<Contract> result = [];
    if (contractList.Count == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    // Get the date range and create the buckets
    int firstDay = contractList.MinBy(c => c.Start)!.Start.DayNumber;
    int lastDay = contractList.MaxBy(c => c.End)!.End.DayNumber;
    int days = lastDay - firstDay + 1;
    var buckets = new Contract[days];

    int DayIndex(DateOnly date) => date.DayNumber - firstDay;

    // Fill buckets
    foreach (var contract in contractList) {
        for (int day = DayIndex(contract.Start); day <= DayIndex(contract.End); day++) {
            if ((buckets[day]?.Priority ?? 0) < contract.Priority) {
                buckets[day] = contract;
            }
        }
    }

    // Gather results
    int i = 0;
    while (i < buckets.Length) {
        Contract currentContract = buckets[i];
        int start = i;
        while (i < buckets.Length && buckets[i] == currentContract) { i++; }
        if (currentContract is not null) {
            result.Add(currentContract with {
                Start = DateOnly.FromDayNumber(firstDay + start),
                End = DateOnly.FromDayNumber(firstDay + i - 1)
            });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This one is much clearer. Thank you. With other one I had to start searching for the documentation of each new concepts for me that I saw there which overwhelemed me. but thank you :)